# Manhwa where FL leaves a wedding for the ML to another woman and is assassinated in her carriage

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

There's this Manhwa I read a long time ago where the FL thought the ML hated her and doesn’t attend his wedding and then is assassinated in her carriage ride away. One of her guards returns to tell the ML that she's died and he gets upset and kills the guard.  She's then reincarnated.

Comment: Can you add any more details at all? Rough publishing timeframe, when/where was it set, etc?

Comment: When she is reincarnated, is it into her own body or another's? The past, present, or future? The same world or a different one?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[A Stepmother's Märchen](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/m12y3ml/the-fantasie-of-a-stepmother)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> They called her the Iron Widow. When her husband died, he left her to manage not only his vast holdings but also his four children. Young and inexperienced, Shuri nonetheless tried her best to raise them, despite their bitter attitude towards her. She is finally free to live her own life as her eldest son marries... only to find herself mysteriously reset to seven years ago—the night of her husband's funeral. Can Shuri find happiness with this second chance at a new destiny?

Shuri, a teenage girl from a minor noble family, is pressured into an arranged marriage with a marquess who already has four prepubescent children from a previous wife. The marquess dies of pneumonia two years later, leaving her as the head of the household, a responsibility she doesn't particularly want but feels obliged to fulfill. She believes that her stepchildren resent her and don't really want her around.

Seven years later, her eldest stepson, Jeremy, is about to marry, at which point he's due to over as the head of the head of the household. Shuri is relieved that she'll no longer be required to fulfill that role, and on the day of Jeremy's wedding, informs the servants that she'll be leaving the household in secret to start a new life elsewhere. However, the carriage she leaves in is attacked while passing through a forest and she's murdered in the process. It's presumed that the attack was carried out by bandits.

She then wakes up seven years in the past, on the day of her late husband's funeral. It's also revealed much later in the story that the attack on the carriage was a pre-planned assassination.

[image] [image]